# Is there a maximum font size for body copy on desktop websites?

Tags: readability

Similar to this post [Is there an optimal font size?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/211/is-there-an-optimal-font-size). But for maximum readable font sizes. Or when does a font size become too big and decreases readability?

I understand there a lots of variables; screen size, distance, font, weights, etc... However, is there any specific literature on the topic?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there necessary is a maximum font size, as designers seem to be moving away from absolute measures, which changes depending on screen resolution, device aspect ratio, device size, viewing distance, etc.

What you need to consider perhaps is the density of the content that is optimal for your audience (e.g. [optimal line length](https://baymard.com/blog/line-length-readability)), and other factors that might affect legibility and readability for the chosen font. This gives you more flexibility to scale your design to.